# Eclipse How To Import External Library's Documentation

Tags: eclipse

When we import the external library to eclipse Java project, we can use the auto-correction feature of eclipse for the imported methods from new libraries but we can't see what the methods specifically do. We have to import library's documentation.

**Question1:** How can I import documentation into eclipse project?

**Question2:** What does Java Documentation look like?

**Question3:** Which file format does Java documentation use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Right click on your project->properties->java build path
- select the libraries (its generally .jar file)
- click on the dropdown of the libraries to expand the settings-> select source attachment none and click on edit
- select the source to the doc ( java documents generally represented by JavaDoc)
- click okay.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is how it works in the latest versions of Eclipse.

Any chance we could get an updated answer?

Comment: I haven't tried this with the latest version. However there are few detailed options provided on this link: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Answer (score 3):

> **Question1: How can I import documentation into eclipse project?**

In the project explorer, right-click on the library and select Properties. In the resulting dialog, choose "Javadoc Location" and complete the information.

> **Question2: What is Java Documentation looks like?**

A set of directories with HTML files for each class. There is typically an `index.hml` at the root, plus often a `package-list` file too. Eclipse searches for these when you "validate" the location.

> **Question3: Which file format java documentation using?**

Eclipse accepts a URL (to a file or a web page), a ZIP or a JAR.

Comment: if my documentation file format is xhtml ? how can i import ? Because as you said eclipse searches for .html or package-list format.Eclipse can't find the xhtml format i guess.

Comment: Is your documentation actually [JavaDoc documentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc)? If it isn't, Eclipse won't be able to use it AFAIK.

Comment: I took the documentation from where i took .jar files.They wrote that the javadoc file format is xhtml.And they say        " The unique look-and-feel is added later by executing the following ant command:
ant -f build.develope.xml www "

Comment: I tried it but nothing happened.Now i understand that maybe the site doesn't support anymore or they have removed the documentation.I looked up the site and couldn't find anything about documentation.

Answer (score 1):

as far as i know for your Question1: How can i import documentation into eclipse project?

suppose you are using AXIS.jar and u want to get its doc properties then :

1. In the Package Explorer view expand your project and its library folder for the Axis library.
2. Right-click the Axis jar and select Properties.
3. In the Properties dialog, select Javadoc Location in the tree on the left.
4. With the Javadoc URL option selected, click Browse.
5. Navigate to the appropriate folder (see table that follows) and click OK twice to exit the Properties dialog.

Question2: What is Java Documentation looks like? and Question3:Which file format java documentation using?

HTML,zip or jar i guess :))

and

Answer (score 1):

1. In your package explorer (and most likely on other places as well) you can see your jar file (the external library). Right click on that and choose 'properties'. There you've got the options to attach the sources and the javadoc. After you've done that you can view their javadoc as you view your own (i.e. hover, 'javadoc-view', F3 ...)
2. Formatted text
3. Javadoc http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html

Answer (score 0):

COvayurt, you cannot see what methods do specifically because you have added libraries for those methods not the java docoumentation for those libraries, so in order to add java doc for libraries simply provide the path of your docs location(if you have got docs for those libraries).
right click on your project then under properties set the javadoc path.

java documentation are html files created from the standard classes.you can create java doc for your own project too. [see this link](http://www.cs.laurentian.ca/aaron/cosc1047/eclipse-tutorials/javadoc-tutorial.html)

and if you want to see standard java api documentation [here-it-is](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)